# How to get user`s information in react native app on iOS?

Tags: ios, react-native

I have some login form and I need to automatically fill it with the user`s info (first name, last name, email, etc). I think it should be data from Apple ID. Is this possible? How can I do this? What lib should I use? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apple does not allow you acces to this data. Your only option would be to ask the user access to their contacts and select them self from that list.

Comment: Asking user for permissions is not a problem. Is there a lib that allows to get info after asking permissions?

Comment: Asking for libraries if offtopic for Stackoverflow. Also I'm not aware on any way that you will get the information about the logedin user, without the user providing it them selfs.